# change order new tableview items come in

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

Im trying to find a simple way to change the order of my tableview. I want it to start at the top like normal but if a new cell comes the newest cell is at the top. I have found a lot of information on here about flipping the table to start at the bottom but not the way I need it. Any help would be awesome thanks. [Photo Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARf04.jpg)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return expenses.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! expenseTableViewCell

    let expense = expenses[indexPath.row]

    cell.expenseName.text = expense.ename
    cell.expenseCost.text = "$" + expense.ecost!
    cell.expenseDue.text = expense.edue`

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the new item at position 0 in the data model array.

```
items.insert(item, at: 0)
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: @TaiZion So I would place it like this?  `code`public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! expenseTableViewCell
        
        let expense = expenses[indexPath.row]
        expenses.insert(expense, at: 0)
        tableView.reloadData()`code`

Comment: @Sam no, can you please post your code? I will look at your code structure and data model and will update my answer

Comment: @Sam can you add the full code please? Where you instantiate expenses, add new items etc

Answer (score 0):

Table view cells go in whatever order you put them in. Your table view data source will have a method called `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. The second argument is an `IndexPath` that tells you which row needs a cell. So you decide the order by looking at the index path and deciding what data should appear at that location. If you want something to be at the top of the table, check for an index path with row and section equal to zero.

You should have a data model of some kind, maybe as simple as an array. If you add a new entry in the array at index zero, your table view data source code will probably take care of the rest. If that doesn't work out, edit your question to add some more details about how your code currently works.